# Execute something while element is in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the Jquery inview plugin and I am trying to load some elements whenever the user reached the footer of the page. While doing this, I discovered a bug where if the user holds the scroll-click and drags the mouse towards the bottom, in some cases the elements will not load anymore until the footer is out of the view and then back into the view.
Here is the function that I have so far to load the elements when the footer is in the viewport:

```
//Infinite load function. Uses jquery.inview
    $scope.addMoreElements = function(){            
        $scope.limitElementsPerPage += 16;            
        $('.footer').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
            if (isInView) {
                // element is now visible in the viewport                    
                $scope.limitElementsPerPage += 16;
            } else {
                // element has gone out of viewport
                //do nothing
            }
        });
    };
```

I am using Angularjs as well as jQuery for this project. Essentially, what I think I need is something that checks at about 1-2 seconds if the element is still in view. I am not exactly sure I should do this at the moment. This is what I tried to do to solve this issue:

```
$scope.$watch($('.footer'), function(){
        $('.footer').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                while(isInView){
                    console.log('test')                
                }
            }, 1000);               
        });
    });
```

This unfortunately, will crash the browser (I am not sure how I would go about doing this with the setTimeout or the other related functions).

Any help or ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

InView adds a new event for elements, that triggers when the element enters the viewport. Probably some times you just have the footer in the viewport at all times, so that is why it fails.

I think you need to redesign the logic of the page to use the 'scroll' event on whatever element contains the added items and scrolls for the infinite view and in that event to check if the footer is in the viewport, not if it enters.

Personally I use this extension for checking if it is in the viewport:

```
(function($) {

   $.inviewport = function(element, settings) {
var wh=$(window).height();
var wst=$(window).scrollTop();
var et=$(element).offset().top;
var eh=$(element).height();
       return !(wh + wst <= et)&&!(wst >= et + eh);
   };

   $.extend($.expr[':'], {
       "in-viewport": function(a, i, m) {
           return $.inviewport(a);
       }
   });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I see. Will it also work on mobile? I had some difficulty using scrollTop() and offset() on mobile and this is why I used inview.

Comment: My blog uses it and I have had no issues with it. On the other hand it may be a problem having infinite scroll on slow mobiles, as they have to render an increasingly large page. It's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of functions you can use:

```
      var getScrollY = function(){
          var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
          var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");

          var y = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? 
                  document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;  
          return y;
      }

      function get_elem_y( elem ) {
          var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
          return box.top + getScrollY();
      }
```

And then you can listen to the scroll event, assume footer is something like `<div id="footer">...</div>`

```
  var footer = document.getElementById("footer"); // get footer
  var b_foot_visible = false;
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
       var y = get_elem_y(footer);
       var pageHeight =  ( window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight);
       if((getScrollY() + pageHeight) > y ) {
            // footer is visible
            if(!b_foot_visible) {
                // TODO: add something
                b_foot_visible = true;
            }
       } else {
            // footer is not visible
            if(b_foot_visible) {
                // TODO: remove something
                b_foot_visible = false;
            }
       }
  });
```

Thus, when the scrollY + pages height reaches the footer elements Y coordinate you can do something to display things for the footer.

You might also add check in the beginning to test if the footer is already visible.